# create new ini and update parameters using spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

I have two parameters and I passed that using ajax in my function.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tmax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView tmax(@RequestParam("id") String id,@RequestParam("name") String name) {

}
```

After assigning this two parameters, It should append in **test.ini** file.
Now I need to create **test.ini** file and update these two parameters.

**test.ini**

```
[PARAMS]

param1 =""
param2 = ""
```

How I can do this please help me

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik the problem is i don't know, How to do that

Answer (score 1):

first you must create file if not exist:

```
File test = new File("test.ini")
```

you can validate file is exist by :

```
if (tmpDir.exists() ){//do something}
```

after that you should read file content:

```
FileInputStream fio = new FileInputStream(file,System.in);
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
while(fio.hasNext()){
     srt.append(fio.nextLine())
}
fio.close();
System.out.println(str.toString());
```

you should see file content
after that you can override you content in your bussiness

Comment: How can i store my params inside the ini

Comment: FileOutputStream flo = new FileOutPutStream(str);
flo.save();